# Determine (without using a calculator) which of the following is bigger: $1+\sqrt[3]{2}$ or $\sqrt[3]{12}$

Tags: calculus

I have encountered the following question in a highschool book in the subject of powers. and, it seems I can't solve it....

Determine (without using a calculator) which of the following is bigger: $1+\sqrt[3]{2}$ or $\sqrt[3]{12}$

Any ideas?

Thank you!
Shir

Comment: You know that we can calculate this numerically without a calculator, right?  Paper and pencil, a slide rule, or my old CRC book all still work.

Answer (score 10):

There is a [known inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality) between the arithmetic mean and the cubic mean. It says that for nonnegative $x$ and $y$ we have:
$$
\frac{x+y}{2} \leq \sqrt[3]{\frac{x^3+y^3}{2}}.
$$
If we set $x = 1$ and $y = \sqrt[3]{2}$, we get
$$
\frac{1 + \sqrt[3]{2}}{2} \leq \sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}}.
$$
By multiplying both parts by $2$ we get $1 + \sqrt[3]{2} \leq \sqrt[3]{12}$.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $1+\root 3\of 2\geq \root 3 \of {12}$. Cubing gives
$$1+3\root 3\of 2 + 3\root 3\of 4 + 2\geq 12\ ,$$
or
$$\root 3\of 2+\root 3\of 4\geq 3\ .\tag{1}$$
Now from $2000<2197=13^3$ we can deduce that $\root 3\of 2<1.3$, whence $\root 3\of 4< 1.69$. The last two facts together contradict $(1)$; therefore our original assumption was false. It follows that
$$1+\root 3\of 2\leq \root 3 \of {12}\ .$$

Answer (score 3):

Some times us mathematicians tend to avoid thinking "easily" first =) $$\sqrt[3]{12}-\sqrt[3]{2}=\sqrt[3]{2}(\sqrt[3]{6}-1)\geq 1$$

Comment: Doesn't look much easier than the original problem. Am I missing something? How do you justify the last inequality in the chain?

Comment: I agree with Dan, $\sqrt[3]{6}-1<1$

Comment: Haha of course $\sqrt[3]{6}-1<1$. What I meant is that $\sqrt[3]{6}-1\geq \frac{\sqrt[3]{4}}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$.

Comment: @user121314 OK, how do you get that? I still don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=(1+\sqrt[3]{2})^3$, and we want to know if it is bigger than 12.
$(y-3)^3/54=y$, but $(12-3)^3/54=13{1\over 2}$
$z=(x-3)^3/54-x$ is concave up if $x>3$, $z(3)<0$ so $z(x)$ has one zero (namely $y$) for $x>3$.
$z(12)=3/2>0$ so $12>y$

Answer (score 0):

After reading your helpfull answers, got something of my own:
$ (1+\sqrt[3]{2})<\sqrt[3]{12} \iff (1+\sqrt[3]{2})^3<12 \iff 1+3\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4} +2 < 12 \iff 3\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4} < 9 \iff \sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4} < 3 \iff 2+3\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4}+4 < 27 \iff 3\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4} < 21 \iff \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{4} < 7 $ and the last inequality is true since $\sqrt[3]{2}<2$ and $\sqrt[3]{4}<4$

Thank you all for your answers!!

Comment: This doesn't work. When you expand $(\sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{4})^3$, you should get $2 + 3 \sqrt[3]{16} + 3\sqrt[3]{32} + 4$.